# Microsoft Azure VM high network latency

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We newly setup Microsoft Azure 1core VM (Region SouthEastAsia) running a website. When we try to access home page from India, it loads after a considerable delay of 3sec to 7sec when there was no load on the server. The delay is consistent, and observed for other pages also. 
firebug screen shows waiting time around 1600 ms

Q1: Is this a known network latency issue with Azure ?, if no How can we reduce the latency?
Q2: What is the Microsoft KPI for network latency ?

Environment: 
Azure VM:  Basic_A1 (1 core, 1.75 GB memory)
Application: LAMP stack (Apache1,php,Mysql)
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Region: SouthEastAsia
Accessed from: India
The response size of the home page: 1.4 MB.

Observations:
1. Not a processing delay: We did a `wget http://localhost/` on the server, and the page download was done within 700ms

2. Previously we had same setup with other vendor, the page load took less than 1sec
3. azure 2 core machine also has the same latency.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first log into an Azure VM and see if you do notice a time latency to the Website. Also you could check from a different ISP and see if the issue persists.

Comment: i tested different ISPs, but the initial roudtrip time is around 500ms on all.

Answer (score 0):

You should try two things:

1. Check Your site with http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ and give us an output (may be as image).
2. Check performance both with azure host name and Your own host name and compare results.

Comment: Below is the pingtom test status:, (but on browser the load time takes more than 3 secs)
Page size
    537.9kB
Load time
    2.28s
Requests
    21

Time Spent per State
Wait  55.85%  
Receive  28.51%  
Connect  14.03%   

DNS  1.60%  
Send  0.00%

Comment: OK, so in my opinion something is wrong on server side. Almost 60% of overall loading time is a "wait" state. Wait state is the state, where web browser waits for data from the server, So wait time seems to be mostly related to the application or web server. If it would be a network problem then connect or send states would be long.
From my experience: check out You web server configuration - if it is Apache or NGINX, try to optimize its konfiguration - default configurations are buggy for most production environments. Also check if You have cache ON - with cache wait time should be lower.